# The text of my textboxes is not changing (info inside)

Tags: c#

I'm building a voice controlled application, and i want to set the text of the textboxes when the user speaks his username and password, however this is not happening, but if i display the string that is recognized using a message

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GrammarBuilder g = new Choices("wissam.h44", "jordan_6");
        Grammar g1 = new Grammar(g);
        Grammar g2 = new Grammar(g);
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Shown);
        Recognizer1.LoadGrammar(g1);
        Recognizer2.LoadGrammar(g2);

   }
    private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Synthesizer1.Speak("Application is loaded.");
        Synthesizer1.Speak("Please Enter Your Email: ");
        Recognizer1.SpeechRecognized +=
        new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer1_SpeechRecognized);
        Recognizer1.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        Recognizer1.Recognize();
        Synthesizer1.Speak("Please Enter Your Password: ");
        Recognizer2.SpeechRecognized +=
        new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer2_SpeechRecognized);
        Recognizer2.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        Recognizer2.Recognize();

    }
    void recognizer1_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string eml = e.Result.Text;
        txtemail.Text = eml;
    }
    void recognizer2_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs r)
    {
        txtpwd.Text = r.Result.Text;
    }
```

So in the speech recognized events, if I put MessageBox.Show(eml) the email is displayed correctly, but the text of the text box is not changing

Answer (score 0):

Most probably recognized text contains new line characters, or something like this.

To isolate this, try specifying concrete string in *SpeechRecognized events, like

```
txtemail.Text = "recognized text";
```

will it work? If yes, inspect string in debugger for specific characters.

Comment: it didnt work, and the problem is in the textbox, is there any properties that i might have changed by mistake, so now i cant programatically set text to it?

Comment: Are you changing correct textbox? Can you change textbox text in designer? You can just try remove and and textbox on the form in the designer - will it help?